# Fastest way to find sub-lists of a fixed length, from a given list of values, whose elements sum equals a defined number

Tags: python, performance, permutation, combinatorics, cartesian-product

In Python 3.6, suppose that I have a list of numbers `L`, and that I want to find all possible sub-lists `S` of a given pre-chosen length `|S|`, such that:

- any `S` has to have length smaller than `L`, that is `|S| < |L|`
- any `S` can only contain numbers present in `L`
- numbers in `S` do not have to be unique (they can appear repeatedly)
- the sum of all numbers in `S` should be equal to a pre-determined number `N`

A trivial solution for this can be found using the Cartesian Product with  `itertools.product`. For example, suppose `L` is a simple list of all integers between 1 and 10 (inclusive) and `|S|` is chosen to be 3. Then:

```
import itertools
L = range(1,11)
N = 8
Slength = 3
result = [list(seq) for seq in itertools.product(L, repeat=Slength) if sum(seq) == N]
```

However, as larger lists `L` are chosen, and or larger `|S|`, the above approach becomes extremely slow. In fact, even for `L = range(1,101)` with `|S|=5` and `N=80`, the computer almost freezes and it takes approximately an hour to compute the result.

My take is that:

- there is a lot of unnecessary computations going on there under the hood, given the condition that sub-lists should sum to `N`
- there is a ton of cache misses due to iterating over possibly millions of lists generated by `itertools.product` to just keep much much fewer

So, my question/challenge is: is there a way I can do this in a more computationally efficient way? Unless we are talking hundreds of Gigabytes, speed to me is more critical than memory, so the challenge focuses more on speed, even if considerations for memory efficiency are a welcome bonus.

Comment: As far as I know, solutions that exist for this problem are O(`N` ** (`Slength` - 1)), which will become unmanageable for large `Slength`.

Comment: @Tomothy32 I guess you meant `|L|` where you wrote `N`, right? It should not depend on the value of `N` in my example above. I wonder if the restriction that the sub-lists' elements having to sum to a given number can be used for early exits (and to avoid wasteful memory writes) when generating the product results

Comment: Sorry, I did mean the length of `L`. Another thing to take into consideration is language. If pure speed is the aim, you should be using something like C++, Java, etc. as opposed to Python. Anyway, I came across a similar problem on LeetCode once, and I digging around I found [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum/discuss/8545/Python-140ms-beats-100-and-works-for-N-sum-(Ngreater2)), which could be helpful.

Comment: Your comprehension runs through **all** 'products', which grows with L and S. It does the sum test on each one.  If only a few pass and are saved memory shouldn't be an issue.  `product` is a generator.

Comment: So I guess the numbers are all positive integers, or at least 0. And it should work for arbitrary numbers or are they distributed in a special way? For example, for a sum N=8 with size S=3 you may eliminate in a first step all numbers of size > 8-3+1, because 6+1+1 would be the only solution for a maximum M=6. For 7 there is no solution.

Comment: @userunknown Yeah, I think I can impose that numbers are non-negative for easiness of handling this. Thus, including zero - in which case there is always a solution provided that `L` is generated from a range of values that starts at minimum at zero at maximum at `N`.

Comment: So S can contain multiple instances of a number, while L doesn't? That's surprising. That 0 and N are always contained in L is surprising too. I would have expected, that L could even contain elements exceeding N. Like (2, 3, 3, 5, 10, 12) should produce a sublist of length 3 and sum 9.

Answer (score 1):

So given an input list and a target length and sum, you want all the *permutations* of the numbers in the input list such that:

1. The sum equals the target sum
2. The length equals the target length

The following code should be faster:

```
# Input
input_list = range(1,101)

# Targets
target_sum = 15
target_length = 5

# Available numbers
numbers = set(input_list)

# Initialize the stack
stack = [[num] for num in numbers]

result = []

# Loop until we run out of permutations 
while stack:
    # Get a permutation from the stack
    current = stack.pop()

    # If it's too short
    if len(current) < target_length:
        # And the sum is too small
        if sum(current) < target_sum:
            # Then for each available number
            for num in numbers:
                # Append said number and put the resulting permutation back into the stack
                stack.append(current + [num])

    # If it's not too short and the sum equals the target, add to the result!
    elif sum(current) == target_sum:
        result.append(current)

print(len(result))
```

Comment: This does not do what I described. Try with the values from my example and you will see. It is not combinations, what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I'm exploring this solution. So far, I notice that it is worse than the naive version for `|S| < 4` but it seems to cut runtime in almost half for `|S| >= 4`, regardless of the size of `|L|`